# Auto logging through facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing following feature to my application.

if user not logged in:

```
Splash screen > Landing Screen > Menu page
```

if user logged in:

```
Splash screen > Menu page
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 300;
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
private static String APP_ID = "371906326298857"; //
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
// public static JSONObject profile;
// ID

// Instance of Facebook Class
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
            long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
            mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            if (access_token != null) {


                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, ActivityMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);

            } else{
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LandingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

I am using facebook code in my LandingActivity.java

```
private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;


    public void loginToFacebook() {
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Profile", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                    LandingAsyncTask myTask = new LandingAsyncTask(
                            LandingActivity.this, LandingActivity.this, profile);
                    myTask.execute();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
```

when i debug `LandingActivity` it shows a value for access_token.
I want to get same access token value in my `SplashScreen.java`, it shows null

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: where did you save access token in shared prefrences?? first you need to save access token in preferences then you can use it anywhere

Comment: @Iqbal I have used, private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

Comment: but you didn't use PutString() in your code... just follow the link  i mention in the answer below you will get what you want

Comment: I fixed it by using >>> if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

thnx alot @iqbal for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code/for more detail visit [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

```
public void loginToFacebook() {
mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

if (access_token != null) {
    facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
}

if (expires != 0) {
    facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
}

if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
    facebook.authorize(this,
            new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
            new DialogListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Function to handle cancel event
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    // Function to handle complete event
                    // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token",
                            facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires",
                            facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError error) {
                    // Function to handle error

                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                    // Function to handle Facebook errors

                }

            });
}
```

}

Comment: What about if access_token is null?